# EF6 Not Working After Column Change [Invalid Column]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have several classes in my real code but for this problem I will focus on the two at hand.  I have a List class which contains a Name and Items.  There is also a Group class which has a name and Items.  The relationship used to be List -> Group (many) -> Items.  The default for our data seemed to trend more toward List -> Items (many) -> Group where an item may, or may not, be grouped.  To accomplish this I simply removed the ListId and navigational item from the Group class.  I am able to load the Items just fine but whenever I try to access the Groups DbSet it gives me the following error:

Invalid column name 'List_ListId'.

Here is the code for the classes and the DbContext.  I am using EF6 (not core).  I have tried recreating the Group class, restarting Visual Studio, restarting SQL Server, and wiping the publish directory to make sure it is clean.  Help?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyProject.Database
{
    [Table("dbo.Lists")]
    public class List
    {
        [Key]
        public int ListId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool SortAsNumeric { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ListItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Database
{
    [Table("dbo.ListGroups")]
    public class ListGroup
    {
        [Key]
        public int ListGroupId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int OrderSequence { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<ListItem> Items { get; set; }

        public ListGroup()
        {
            this.Items = new List<ListItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Database
{
    [Table("dbo.ListItems")]
    public class ListItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int ListItemId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public string Subtext { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }

        public int OrderSequence { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

        public int ListId { get; set; }

        public virtual List List { get; set; }

        public int? ListGroupId { get; set; }

        public virtual ListGroup Group { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ListItemProperty> Properties { get; set; }

        public ListItem()
        {
            this.OrderSequence = 1;
            this.Selected = false;
            this.Properties = new List<ListItemProperty>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Database
{
    public class ListContext : DbContext
    {
        public ListContext() : base("MyConnectionString") {}

        public virtual DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ListItem> Items { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ListGroup> Groups { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ListItemProperty> Properties { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<List>()
                .HasMany(l => l.Items)
                .WithRequired(li => li.List)
                .HasForeignKey<int>(li => li.ListId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ListItem>()
                .HasMany(li => li.Properties)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Item)
                .HasForeignKey<int>(p => p.ListItemId);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The following code is working.  The problem comes when I attempt to access this.Groups in the context.

```
List MyList = Lists
    .Where(x => x.Name == ListName)
    .Include(x => x.Items.Select(i => i.Properties))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `List` and `ListItem`? I suspect you've removed the navigation property from one class but not the other

Comment: The List class was included but I added the ListItem class to the original post.  I also added a sample from my context which IS working.  It is for the Properties being loaded along with the Items.